# Minikube failed to start -> pgrep kube-api

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I am working with kubernetes and minukube to run a cluster locally in my machine, but i got this err:

```
W1118 20:54:48.711968 14383 kubeadm.go:502] pgrep apiserver: command failed: sudo pgrep kube-apiserver
stdout:
stderr: : exit status 1 cmd: sudo pgrep kube-apiserver
I1118 20:54:49.012735 14383 exec_runner.go:42] (ExecRunner) Run: sudo pgrep kube-apiserver
I1118 20:54:49.041602 14383 exec_runner.go:74] (ExecRunner) Non-zero exit: sudo pgrep kube-apiserver: exit status 1 (28.808764ms)
W1118 20:54:49.041655 14383 kubeadm.go:502] pgrep apiserver: command failed: sudo pgrep kube-apiserver
stdout:
stderr: : exit status 1 cmd: sudo pgrep kube-apiserver
I1118 20:54:49.332086 14383 exec_runner.go:42] (ExecRunner) Run: sudo pgrep kube-apiserver
I1118 20:54:49.354256 14383 exec_runner.go:74] (ExecRunner) Non-zero exit: sudo pgrep kube-apiserver: exit status 1 (22.079013ms)
W1118 20:54:49.354306 14383 kubeadm.go:502] pgrep apiserver: command failed: sudo pgrep kube-apiserver
stdout:
stderr: : exit status 1 cmd: sudo pgrep kube-apiserver
I1118 20:54:49.612700 14383 exec_runner.go:42] (ExecRunner) Run: sudo pgrep kube-apiserver
I1118 20:54:49.630745 14383 exec_runner.go:74] (ExecRunner) Non-zero exit: sudo pgrep kube-apiserver: exit status 1 (17.984732ms)
W1118 20:54:49.630837 14383 kubeadm.go:502] pgrep apiserver: command failed: sudo pgrep kube-apiserver
```

i am investigating about it but i didn't found anythin related with it.

Comment: Which OS do you use?

Comment: I am using ubuntu

Comment: You are running minikube with sudo, because it looks that is missing perms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the information that you provided, check yout host configuration, because it looks that it needs permission, and run this:

```
echo "1" >/proc/sys/net/bridge/bridge-nf-call-iptables
```

This modified you OS to enable bridge calls